# Редирект с условием, что главное зеркало домена с www

Tags: .htaccess, https, ssl, домен

Внимание знатоки вопрос! Домен с www, то есть главное зеркало с www. 
Есть htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.site.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.www.site\.ru$ [NC]
```

Редиректит на https во всех случаях правильно, кроме http://www.site.ru/. То есть htt**p**://site.ru -редиректит правильно на http**s**://www.site.ru, а вот htt**p**://**www**.site.ru не редиректит и соединение не защищено.

В чем проблема? Уже всю голову поломал. Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Comment: ПОКА ЧТО, ни один из ответов не подошёл. Не сработало.

Comment: Так а что это за самый последний `RewriteCond`, почему там странное имя `www.www.site.ru` и где обработчик (`RewriteRule`) этого условия?

Answer (score 1):

Так вы перевели сайт на https я правильно понял?
Добавьте этот код

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.site.ru/$1 [L,R=301]
```

но одного этого кода не достаточно для перехода на https в нете есть инструкции даже в хелпе яндекса что и как сделать для перехода на https

Comment: Совершенно верно!

Comment: я вам скинул рабочий код со своего сайта, а вашем случе я не вижу кода редиректа на www с без www возможно в этом и проблема у вас

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ https://site.ru/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.site.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://site.ru/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\&
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\=
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ![^\/]$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: А что значат: следующе строки                                      `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\&
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\=
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.`

Comment: @kelevra 301 редирект со страниц со слешем на без слеша (весь сайт)